# System.IO Exception after IIS deployment

Tags: web, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, web-deployment

MVC 5 project after IIS deployment on browse returns "Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO' or one of its dependencies". Things I have tried via stackoverflow and googling are

1. Clean & Rebuild solution
2. Deleting bing & obj folders
3. Setting website folder access to IIS Users with full access
4. Removing & adding the System.IO.dll
5. Setting propertygroup under .csproj file

Please can anyone help me in getting the cause.

Application is working fine on local machine with no errors. But getting the above error on IIS deployment.

Comment: If you happen to use any modern NuGet packages in such legacy project types, your final deployment is very likely to fail like this. 1) What's the .NET Framework on that server? 2) What exact are the artifacts you deployed to the server? 3) Do all your projects use package references instead of `package.config`? You can try a million things from searching but without such essential analysis you won't find the right direction.

Comment: make sure Systm.Io dll presented in folder then check the DLL version in dll property. After that open package.config or web confg file. Check the version mentioned for system.io dll.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi and RameshKumar for you quick suggestion. The issue is resolved it was  a policy blocker issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the great suggestions. Policy blocker was creating the issue and got resolved after signing system.io dll